# Trying to return a collection from within a class

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following classes below, I want to return all USLocation classes for a specific state:

```
var usLocations = (from s in GetUSStates() where s.Code == stateCode select s.Locations);
```

But I keep getting the error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<A.Model.USLocation>>'
>   to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<A.Model.USLocation>'. An explicit
>   conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Seems like the "select s.Locations is returning a collection within a collection. What am I doing wrong here?

```
public class USState
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<USLocation> Locations { get; set; } 
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}:{1} ({2})", Name, Code, Id);
    }
}

public class USLocation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You should let us know `GetUSStates()` signature...

Comment: I think you need a SelectMany to collapse the location enumerables into a single IEnumerable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are `select`ing collection instead of single item. That's why `usLocation` is `IEnumerable` of `IEnumerable`s. Try using `SelectMany` and (optionally) `ToList`:

```
var usLocations = GetUSStates().Where(s => s.Code == stateCode).SelectMany(s => s.Locations).ToList();
```

and you'll get a list of `USLocation`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx) instead of Select.

Answer (score 0):

```
var usLocations = GetUSStates()
      .Where(state => state.Code == stateCode).Single().Locations;
```

or

```
var usLocations = (from s in GetUSStates()
                   where s.Code == stateCode
                   from l in s.Locations
                   select l);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var usLocations = GetUSStates().Where(s => s.Code == stateCode).First().Locations;
```

EDIT: Your query returns an enumeration containing the result of just one state, itself being an enumeration of locations.